# updateMany from Json Array Request Body in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my request body

```
{"old":[{"coba": "A"}, {"cobak": "B"}], "new":[{"coba": "C"},{"cobak": "D"}]}
```

This is my Code

```
  function getOld(){

        const data = request.body; 
        for(i = 0; i < data.old.lenght; i++) { 
            return data.old[i]
        }
   }

    function getNew(){ 

        const data = request.body; 
        for(i = 0; i < data.new.lenght; i++) { 
            return data.new[i]
        }
    }

    const reqOld = getOld();
    const reqNew = getNew();

    db.cb.updateMany({$and: [reqOld]}, {$set: reqNew}, {upsert: false}, (error, data));
```

The problem is just update first request body as JSON Array and it could not update all document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Look at your spelling of `lenght`.
2. Doing updates this way, with an array of old and an array of new, seems confusing. You should be able to just use the updates and an `_id`
3. You'll likely want to write a loop to go through all of your items. The below is pseudocode -- it's hard to tell what you're actually trying to do

```js
(async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < request.body.old.length; i++) {
    const newItem = request.body.new[i];
    const oldItem = request.body.old[i];
    await db.cb.update(oldItem, {$set: newItem });
  }
})()
```

Comment: Its works but, getting an error : ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: Cannot set headers after they are sent to  the client

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < request.body.old.length; i++) {
    const newItem = request.body.new[i];
    const oldItem = request.body.old[i];
    db.cb.updateMany(oldItem, {$set: newItem }, {upsert: false}, (error, data) => { if(error){response.json(error.message)}else if(data){responden.json(data)});
  }`

Comment: You need to consolidate all of the data that you're trying to send in the response before calling `response.json` -- that method sends the JSON response. I'd recommend looking over a node course to get a handle on how these asynchronous operations work & what's going on here. https://www.coursera.org/learn/server-side-nodejs looks well rated and like it shares the stack that you're trying to work in